# Solving the recurrence relation $h_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} h_{n}+\frac{p_{S}}{n+1}$.

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, integral-equations

I have this specific linear non-constant coefficient, non-homogenous recurrence relation that I'm trying to solve but stuck with. I'll show the recurrence and steps I've done so far.

> Recurrence: $\displaystyle h_{n+1} = \dfrac{n}{n+1} h_{n}+\dfrac{p_{S}}{n+1}$, where $p_{S}$ is a constant between $0$ and $1$. And $n\geq0$, so we assume $h_{0}$ has been given.

I will show the steps I've done so far.

Let $\displaystyle H(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty h_{n}z^n$. Multiplying both sides by $z^n$ and summing from $0$ to $\infty$, we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_{n+1}z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1}h_{n}z^n +p_{S}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n+1}.$$

The LHS is $\dfrac{1}{z}(H(z)-h_{0})$. The second term of the RHS is $\displaystyle\dfrac {p_{S}}{z}\int H(z)dz$.

But I've tried for half an hour to figure out how to write the first term of the RHS in terms of derivatives or integrals of $H(z)$ and I have no idea how to progress. If anyone can provide hints so I can proceed on my own, I'll gladly take it. Thanks so much!

P.S. if I have an integral equation as above of $H(z)$, is it valid to take derivatives to turn it into a differential equation instead?

Comment: Without generating functions, just write it as $\,(n+1)h_{n+1} = n h_{n} + p_{S}\,$ and telescope.

Comment: @dxiv, brilliant thank you so much I just used the telescoping method and it worked, and gave me the sequence limit I wanted. tysm!